# How to load a scene when it completes getting data from firebase?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

there are two scenes in my game.
first one is "main Scene" and second one is "user Data Scene".
in "user data scene" I am retrieving current user data from firebase.

The problem is when I switch to "user data scene" from "main scene" there are no data for few seconds until its retrieved from firebase. it looks very bad to me.

All I want is when user is on "main scene" and try to open "user data scene" it should be not active until retrieving data from firebase is done.

I attached the script that gets data from firebase to the main scene's empty object which does not destroy on load. and calling it in start function of the "user data scene".

I am calling below function in start function of "user data scene".
I want to wait until data is loaded from firebase and value is attached to text objects before activating the "user data scene" ?

```
public IEnumerator getUserDataFromDb(Text userNameTxt, Text totalDiamondTxt, Text totalGoldText) //get data from database of diamond and how much diamond has been sold
{
    userNameTxt.text = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser.DisplayName;
    var getDbTask = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Users").Child(FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser.UserId).GetValueAsync();
    yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => getDbTask.IsCompleted);
    if (getDbTask.Exception != null)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning(getDbTask.Exception.InnerExceptions[0].InnerException.Message);
    }
    else
    {
        DataSnapshot snapshot = getDbTask.Result;
        totalDiamondTxt.text = snapshot.Child("Sell").Child("Total").Child("TotalDiamond").Value.ToString();
        int dbDiamondValue = int.Parse(snapshot.Child("Sell").Child("Total").Child("TotalDiamond").Value.ToString());
        totalGoldText.text = snapshot.Child("Sell").Child("Total").Child("TotalGold").Value.ToString();
        int dbGoldValue = int.Parse(snapshot.Child("Sell").Child("Total").Child("TotalGold").Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Firebase is multi - threading. I think it is hard to make it run synchronous in unity, waiting for all object to load. Just make a coroutines to wait and when you're waiting, just make a test show that you are loading data :v

Comment: Firebase does not have loading status :v, that;s the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
  Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
    var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
    if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available) {
        db = Firebase.Firestore.FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance;
        //use your data and load your secene after
        DocumentReference docRef = 
        db.Collection("yourCollection").Document("yourDocumentCode");
        docRef.GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
          DocumentSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
          if (snapshot.Exists) {
            //do you stuff here after retrieving the info
          } else {
            Debug.Log(String.Format("Document {0} does not exist!", snapshot.Id));
        }
      });
        
    } else {
      UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(System.String.Format("Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
      // Firebase Unity SDK is not safe to use here.
    }
  });
```

Need that for the specific use of firestore, but you got a similar snippet in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup) so that right after you do whatever you need with the firebase services you move on executing your app.

Comment: thank you sir but I am getting data from firebase correctly. I just want to load a scene only when data is completely retrieved from firebase.

Comment: the way to retrieve the data in an asyncronous would be very similar, you can do `docRef.GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
      DocumentSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
      if (snapshot.Exists) { //after you snapshot is retrieved do your tasks  }`

Comment: find a sample snippet in the updated answer. You can find useful ones in the documentation that should fit your needs

Comment: edited question .I think I was not clear with my question. my bad English is causing the problem here. please check my question again.